ValueError: The layer sequential_2 has never been called and thus has no defined input
I have been running different version of the code below to get the activation maps by a certain specified layer for the frames input for predictions. Like i said i tried various different ways but i keep getting the same error. I also tried model(tf.keras.Input((20,64,64 3))) after loading the model. But then i got another error message, saying something like the expected shape and obtained shape do not match. I apologise in advance if the way i presented the issue sounds confusing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AI_Powered_Deepfake_Detection\activation_map.py", line 93, in 
plot_activation_maps(model, video_frames, layer_name)
File "AI_Powered_Deepfake_Detection\activation_map.py", line 63, in plot_activation_maps
activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "AI_Powered_Deepfake_Detection\env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 228, in input
return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(0, "input_tensors", "input")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "AI_Powered_Deepfake_Detection\env\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 259, in _get_node_attribute_at_index
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The layer sequential_2 has never been called and thus has no defined input.
Below is the code i tried to run. Basically I wanted to get the activation maps of the frames input for predictions by a certain specified layer. Here is the model architecture for reference
#################################################################
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu'), input_shape = (SEQUENCE_LENGTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((4, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(32)) #changed to 64 from 32

model.add(Dense(len(CLASSES_LIST), activation = 'softmax'))

######################################################################
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path_to_model')

def frames_extraction(input_video_file_path, model):

# Initialize the VideoCapture object to read from the video file.
video_reader = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_file_path)

# Declare a list to store video frames we will extract.
frames_list = []

# Iterating the number of times equal to the fixed length of sequence.
for _ in range(20):

    # Read a frame.
    success, frame = video_reader.read()

    # Check if frame is not read properly then break the loop.
    if not success:
        break

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)

    # Check if any face was detected
    if face_locations:
        # Assuming there's only one face per frame
        top, right, bottom, left = face_locations[0]

        # Crop the face from the image
        face_frame = frame[top:bottom, left:right]

        # Convert BGR to RGB
        face_frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(face_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Resize the Frame to fixed height and width.
        resized_face_frame = cv2.resize(face_frame_rgb, (64, 64))

        # Normalize the resized frame by dividing it with 255 so that each pixel value then lies between 0 and 1
        normalized_face_frame = resized_face_frame / 255

        # Append the normalized frame into the frames list
        frames_list.append(normalized_face_frame)

video_reader.release()

return np.expand_dims(frames_list, axis = 0)


def plot_activation_maps(model, video_frames, layer_name):
'''
This function will plot the activation maps of the specified layer 
for the given video frames.
Args:
    model:        The trained LRCN model.
    video_frames: A list containing the extracted frames from a 
    video.
    layer_name:   The name of the layer for which the activation 
    maps are to be plotted.
'''
# Create a model that outputs the activations of the specified layer.
activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, 
outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)

# Get the activations for the video frames.
activations = 
activation_model.predict(np.expand_dims(video_frames, axis=0))[0]

# Determine the number of filters in the specified layer.
num_filters = activations.shape[-1]

# Plot the activations for each filter.
for frame_index, frame_activations in enumerate(activations):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, num_filters, figsize=(20, 20))
    fig.suptitle(f'Frame {frame_index + 1} Activations', 
    fontsize=16)
    
    for filter_index in range(num_filters):
        ax = axes[filter_index]
        ax.imshow(frame_activations[:, :, filter_index], 
         cmap='viridis')
        ax.axis('off')
    
    plt.show()



layer_name = 'time_distributed_20'

input_video_file_path = "path_to_video"

video_frames = frames_extraction(input_video_file_path, model)

plot_activation_maps(model, video_frames, layer_name)

